# undefined output while using mergeMap in Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Theoretically, I know what mergeMap is and how it works, but when I try to understand using
practical approach I get confused, this is what I have done so far

```
const input1$= of("value 1","value 2","value 3");
const input2$= of(1,2,3,4);
const obs=input1$.pipe(
            mergeMap(data1=>{
              return input2$
              .pipe(map(ch=>{ch+' '+data1}))})
        )
```

unfortunately, I am getting undefined when I try to merge them, your help would be appreciated to make me understand how it works.

Comment: you don't have a return in your pipe `return ch+' '+data1`

Comment: can you show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything in your second pipe

Try this

```js
const obs=input1$.pipe(
            mergeMap(data1=>{
              return input2$
              .pipe(map(ch=>{
              return ch+' '+data1
              }))})
        )
```

Comment: Thank you @Bogdan Chereghi, I gave you +1 and accepted as an answer

Comment: @RussianFederation Thank you